# How do I sign the Leadership Code of Conduct?

Tags: community

In addition to the [Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/conduct) there is the the [Leadership Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/leadership-conduct).

Can I sign the Leadership Code of Conduct like the *regular* Code of Conduct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently not possible due to this bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-community/+bug/392976

So just make the mental checkbox in your head I guess. :)